# not on PATH warning

Tags: python

I know this has been asked, but I'm getting this not on PATH warning and I'm very new to Python and I'm not sure if answers for other questions apply to my situation.

WARNING: The script pycodestyle.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

When I'm in bash and I enter >>> pycodestyle file.py I get

> > > > pycodestyle spin.py   File "", line 1
> > > >           pycodestyle spin.py
> > > >             ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What I'm wondering is if there is an alternate command I should be using to run pycodestyle, because instead of using the command $ python file.py to run a program in bash, I have to use $ wintpy py file.py to run it. To install pycodestyle I had to use $ py -m pip install pycodestyle instead of $ pip install pycodestyle or the other two or three commands I tried to install it.

So my questions are
1 Is it possible I'm just not using the right command? If so, what can I try? 
2 Do I need to add the directory to PATH? If so, how do I do that? I've looked some different ways to do that in forums and videos and whatnot but it is pretty unclear to me how I need to do it. I'm not sure if I was looking at outdated info or what. I had everything set up fine til about a week ago I had to reset my computer and I had to add admin privileges and change ownerships. I guess I shouldn't have used my microsoft account for my user account? Sorry for the long winded question, go easy on me, it's my first question on a programming site. Thanks for your help! Oh and I'm running py 3.8.2 on windows 10

Comment: `>>>` is not a bash prompt, it's a Python prompt (or, something that's not valid syntax, if you're literally entering `>>>` as part of your input). `pycodestyle` is an external command you can run from a shell, as opposed to something you can invoke from a Python interpreter as Python syntax.

Comment: That said, the error implies that you're typing a *shell* command at a *Python* prompt.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry noob mistake, when I run it on the command line I get bash: pycodestyle: command not found. I guess that means I need to add the directory to path? If so, I'm still not quite sure how to do that

Comment: Do I go to environment variables, then in the box labeled "User variables for me" select Path       C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps and change it to Path   C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe?

Comment: When you installed `pycodestyle`, there should have been a shim for it created (I don't know what file extension those shims have on Windows these days; it might be `.exe`, but it could also be `.bat` or `.py` or something else). Add the directory that _contains_ that shim to your path (on Windows it'll typically end in `Scripts` if my memory serves; by contrast, on UNIX the directory ends in `bin`).

Comment: By contrast, if you installed it in a virtualenv, be sure you activate that same virtualenv before you try to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles! Ok, I see I have pycodestyle.exe in the Scripts folder, but I'm not sure how to add Scripts to Path. Would I go to Environment Variables and in User variables for me, then click New, then for Variable name  put in Path, and for Variable value put in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts or would I change the Path that is already in there?

Comment: Adding `Scripts` as a new entry should work.

Comment: Got it! That worked Charles, thanks so much for your help!